# How to use external images in PDF using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I want to embed some external images to pdf i am using  tag for doing this but image is not display in pdf. How to show external images inside pdf

Comment: Make sure when using wicked_pdf you write the complete url rather than using the path of the image.

Comment: Yes I am using external images full path but it is not displayed in pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this version of [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368&can=2&q=).

This may solve your problem.

Comment: Link broken, which version was it?